# Get time passed in Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, scripting, coroutine

I am working on a simple game in Unity3d.

I've created a `Coroutine` that does something after a specific amount of time with `WaitForSecond`.

But in some states it stops with `StopCoroutine()`.

I want to know if it is possible to get the time of the `Coroutine` when it has stopped.

I mean when `Coroutine` stop give me a digit number like 23 second or 54 second or something like that.

Comment: It's possible but you need to post the the code to show what you're timing

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
stopWatch.Stop();
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

// Format and display the TimeSpan value.
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
ts.Milliseconds / 10);
Debug.Log("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
```

If you want to only get the time passed if it's stopped, try something like this:

```
Coroutine testCoroutine = StartCoroutine(yourCoroutine());
```

Then, when you stop the coroutine with `StopCoroutine(testCoroutine);`, you can return from the Stopwatch function documented above. Or, you can always add `Time.deltaTime` to a variable and return that as a float. That'll give you seconds and milliseconds.

*EDIT* After author posted his code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class sdfsd : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(WaitUntilAPressed());
    }
    IEnumerator WaitUntilAPressed()
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        yield return new WaitUntil(()=> Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A));

        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Debug.Log(elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val millis = measureTimeMillis {

        // Do Stuff

    }     
    val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
    Log.d(TAG, "Time: $seconds seconds")
}
```